# JavaScript:Not able to insert image at cursor position of webview with specific Height and Width

Tags: javascript, android, html, android-webview

I'm trying to implement RichTextEditor using WebView.

I used following code to insert image. it's working perfectly.

```
webview.loadUrl("javascript: 
                   (function () { document.execCommand('insertImage', 'false','"
                + selectedImagePath +"');})()");
```

To specify height and width I used following command but it's not working.

```
String imagSpec =   " width=" + 200 + " height=" + 200 + " border= 5" ;
webview.loadUrl("javascript(function () {     
        document.execCommand('insertImage', 'false','"
        + selectedImagePath +imagSpec+ "');})()");
```

Please help me to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following Code worked for me.

```
  String exeSucess="document.execCommand('insertHtml', false,'<img   +
  src=\"http://www.developphp.com/images/home_over.png\" +
  height=200 width=auto style=\"object-fit=contain;\"></img>');";
```

Instead of calling 'insertImage' Command, I used 'insertHtml' ,to insert image tag at cursor position.

Thanks